# How to enable leader election for high-availability Kubernetes on Google Compute Engine?

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, high-availability

I'm trying to run kubernetes in high-availability mode on GCE following the [instructions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/ha-master-gce/), but my `kube-scheduler.manifest` and `kube-controller-manager.manifest` don't have the `--leader-elect=true` flag set on any of the masters.

I dug around in the [salt templates](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/saltbase/salt/kube-scheduler/kube-scheduler.manifest), and it appears to me that there is no configuration option to enable it. Further, the [high-availability proposal](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/ha_master.md) suggests that the flag should be enabled even in "non-replicated mode", but it doesn't appear to be.

What is the proper way to enable leader election for kube-scheduler and kube-controller-manager? Is there a way to do it without resorting to [modifying the salt tars myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614039/should-i-edit-the-salt-tar-files-after-a-kubernetes-cluster-is-running-on-google)?

The [high-availability instructions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/high-availability/) mention enabling the `--leader-elect` flag, but the [high-availability setup instructions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/ha-master-gce/) don't explain exactly how to do it. The [high-availability proposal doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/ha_master.md) says this about leader election: "We will use the same configuration in non-replicated mode to simplify deployment scripts", but I can't find evidence of that in the salt templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of the `leader-elect` flag is `true` as of Kubernetes v1.4.0, so in the absence of explicit configuration the leader election client should be enabled.

You may also want the set the `apiserver-count` flag of the Kubernetes API server according to the number of masters you spin-up (defaults to `1`). It gives the master elected components (scheduler, controller-manager) a hint about the size of the quorum formed by the masters, because the leader election process uses the Raft consensus.

References:

- [kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-scheduler/)
- [kube-controller-manager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-controller-manager/)
- [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kube-apiserver/)
- [PR #29207](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/6fd685b54b4ebaf502a60331bbb6e334226da988)
- [PR #18626](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/a09d85bd83cabffdd466fd7a88e39cb3438044ce)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! What does the apiserver-count flag do exactly?

Comment: It's determines the size of the quorum formed by the masters. I updated my answer with the explanation.